# Also can't rebuild DB using EF Codefirst Seed method not being executed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Yet another issue after redesigning the database I cannot seem to get it working. I think I have done all that I can see on Stackoverflow but I am sure someone will point out my folly. Too tied and frustrated to look thru all the existing questions.

I ran all the Package Manager Console scripts ending with Update-Database.
At first it created all the old tables and then one of the new ones and then it tried to create the same new table twice and so stopped there. I ended up deleting them manually thru Server Explorer even though all the models do not exist. I deleted them manually and re-ran Update-Database and that seem to create only the new ones this time, so the mind boggles how that works. Anyhow my problem now is that I also changed the Seed method to populate one of my tables however it does not seem to have executed. Any advice would be gladly received.

Comment: Depending on where you are, dev, test deployed to production, etc. you may just want to start over. Delete the migrations folder and the __Migrations table in the database. Now add an empty migration to establish a baseline (Add-Migration Baseline -IgnoreChange) and do an  update-database. Now you should be able to follow the normal code first workflow (model change, migration).

Comment: I have done as you suggested however my Seed method is still not getting executed as my table is empty

Comment: What database initializer are you using? http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/

Comment: Try doing another update-database. Even without a new migration it should run the seed method. The output I see is "No pending explicit migrations. Running Seed method."

Comment: I am using CreateDatabaseIfNotExists if that matters

Comment: When you ran the baseline migration did it create the __Migration table and insert a record? Try doing an update-database to see if the Seed runs. Try adding a single field to an existing table and see if the migration process does as expected.

Comment: Yes it did create the __Migration table and create an entry. When u say add a field, do you mean thru Server Explorer or thru code. And do I need to run the Add-Migration Baseline -IgnoreChange and Update-Database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93303/discussion-between-glen-and-steve-greene).

Answer (score 1):

Glad you figured it out. Entity Framework has 2 Seed methods. One is for database initialization and only runs when the database is created. The migration seed will run anytime you run update-database and therefore you need to test for existing data using AddOrUpdate or another method.